# Internet explorer 9 version on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues in Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187196/issues-in-internet-explorer-9)

IE->not reading file and as in firefox----> s(input_id).files is giving file details and IE----> it is null or undefined value. so let me know how to read file in IE. how do i get file size, file name etc in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to access the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList) on the client side using something like `document.getElementById("input_id").files`.

The `files` method is part of the [`File API`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) and not supported by IE9. However, IE10 [supports it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).